# How do I modify a borrowed struct's field in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have a `&mut` reference to a struct. I want to reassign a field of the referenced struct, but I only get `cannot assign to current_node.parameter because it is borrowed`.

I have also tried `let ref mut` in the `current_node` declaration, but the same issue happened.

```
pub fn create_ars_tree() {
    let mut top_level_node = NodeItem {
        key: StringOrNodeItems::Text(String::new()),
        parameter: StringOrNodeItems::Text(String::new()),
        parent_item: None,
    };
    let mut current_node = &mut top_level_node; //Reference to the currently edited node
    let mut current_part = &current_node.key; //Reference to the currently edited string
    for current_char in "abcdef".chars() {
        if current_char == '{' {
            //Handle new opening bracket
            match current_part {
                StringOrNodeItems::Text(text) => {
                    current_node.key = StringOrNodeItems::Keys(vec![
                        NodeItem {
                            key: StringOrNodeItems::Text(text.to_string()),
                            parameter: StringOrNodeItems::Text(String::new()),
                            parent_item: Some(current_node)
                            //parent_item: None
                        }
                    ]);
                },
                StringOrNodeItems::Keys(keys) => {
                    unimplemented!();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NodeItem<'a> {
    key: StringOrNodeItems<'a>,
    parameter: StringOrNodeItems<'a>,
    parent_item: Option<&'a NodeItem<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum StringOrNodeItems<'a> {
    Text(String),
    Keys(Vec<NodeItem<'a>>),
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `current_node.key` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:14:6
   |
8  |     let mut current_part = &current_node.key; //Reference to the currently edited string
   |                            ----------------- borrow of `current_node.key` occurs here
...
12 |             match current_part {
   |                   ------------ borrow later used here
13 |                 StringOrNodeItems::Text(text) => {
14 |                     current_node.key = StringOrNodeItems::Keys(vec![
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `current_node.key` occurs here
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0e68aef7a325c1e1378a409cdd5eccf)</sup>

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping with the question. While creating an MRE I accidentally came to a solution to my problem. Question closed I guess

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. The issue is that I am trying to assign `current_node` inside a block borrowing that same variable. If you replace `Some(current_node)` with `None` it compiles